# How do I get Team Build to show test results and coverage for xUnit.net test suite?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, xunit.net

Has anybody had any success getting Team Build to show xUnit.net test results and code coverage in the build report?  The MSBuild runner is running the tests just fine and the results are in the log file, but the test results and code coverage results areas of the build report say "No test result" and "No coverage result" respectively.  Is Team Build looking for a certain location / format for the test results to be exported by the xUnit.net runner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFS/TeamBuild definitely requires the test results in a particular format, they also need to be specifically published to TFS as well.

I'm currently looking at this problem for the Gallio test runner, and can offer two potential options:

1. Try wrapping the xUnit tests inside the 'Generic Test' project type
   that VSTS offers - this is where MSTest executes the xUnit test
   runner.
2. Come up with an XSLT transform (or similar) that can map the
   xUnit results to the MSTest schema (see
   http://www.codeplex.com/nunit4teambuild for an example of this
   approach for NUnit tests).

Answer (score 0):

See also http://jonnekats.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/integrate-xunit-tests-into-your-daily-team-build/