# How to publish test result files (.trx) to TFS 2013

Tags: batch-file, tfs, build, msbuild

**Status:**

I have a TFS 2013 installation on a dedicated machine and I modified the build template so that it just runs a `batch file` (no Visual Studio project required), which we commit on our repository. While this batch file runs, it builds our code and runs some custom test suites, which the test output are multiple `JUnit XML` files.

I already found a way on how I can convert the `JUnit XML` to `.trx files` via batch, but now I'm stuck when it comes to *publishing* those results to TFS.

I found out that there are multiple ways to do that, but unfortunately no way is possible on our build agent right now.

**I tried:**

- Use the *TfsPublisher*, which is described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/12/06/publishing-test-results-through-command-line-test-runner.aspx) - I can't do that because we don't have Visual Studio on our build agent machine installed
- Use *MSTest.exe* as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182488(v=vs.120).aspx), but I can't do that either because -again- we don't have Visual Studio on our build agent machine installed

**Question:**

So is there an alternative way which I haven't found yet to publish the .trx files to TFS? There must be a solution. I can't be the first person who tries to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing all of Visual Studio, you could install the Test Agents for Visual Studio which is much smaller:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40750

Comment: Hi and thank your for your answer! I installed the test agent package on our server, but unfortunately MSTest does not provide the /publish options which we need. Only paid versions of the test agent package have it (source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1224704/527718). Other ideas?

Comment: If you are licensed for TFS you should be licensed for using the test agent or VisualStudio for building/testing purposes.

Comment: Indeed we are! I'm a bit lost where I should put our licence for the Test Agents then...?